# Increase space at bottom of slide in Beamer presentation template?

Tags: beamer

For example, if I want to add a publication citation but run out of space in the `Beamer` preset box area at the bottom of the slide, how can I make some room?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\title[MY LONG PUBLICATION CITATION IS HERE]{My Title}

\author{My name}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the 'font size'. `\title[\resizebox{0.3\paperwidth}{!}{MY LONG PUBLICATION CITATION IS HERE}]{My Title}`. Can try as much as `0.33\paperwidth`. I didn't post as an answer because this doesn't deal with the actual title of the question.

Comment: How do you want to deal with it? As it stands, your question is not very clear. Do you want to use a different theme? To change the size of the text? To have a deeper box throughout the document? A deeper box for the title page? A wider box throughout? A wider box for the title page? Or do you want to put the text somewhere outside the box? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [image: MWE]

For this task you can redefine the bottom bar with `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{...}`  as you want:`

Only as an example from scratch, here is an way to make a bar with `tabularx`, but the right point to start probably is modify the original template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title[MY LONG PUBLICATION CITATION IS HERE]{My Title}
\author{My name}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{
>{\centering}p{.2\paperwidth}
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}p{.2\paperwidth}}
\cellcolor{structure!50}\centering\vspace{-4pt}\insertauthor& 
\cellcolor{structure!70}\centering\vspace{-4pt}\insertshorttitle& 
\cellcolor{structure}\centering\vspace{-4pt}\insertdate\\
\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```